# Java Casting to superclass not change object type?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I don't understand why this code outputs false. Java uses the **object type (not reference)** to choose the [instance] method to execute, in this case, **initial object type is Owl** (with method returns false), anyway, We cast this type to "Nocturnal" (not necessary, but We do). I have **isBlind()** method in the interface and the class.

Why our `Owl` converted to `Nocturnal` using a explicit Cast prints false, if the object type now is Nocturnal and the Nocturnal method prints true?

```
interface Nocturnal {
    default boolean isBlind() {
        return true;
    }
}

public class Owl implements Nocturnal {
    public boolean isBlind() {
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Nocturnal nocturnal = (Nocturnal) new Owl();
        System.out.println(nocturnal.isBlind());
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply said: Casting doesn't change anything about the object. Your nocturnal is an Owl and allways will be an Owl and even casting to Object won't change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A powerful way to think about OO programming is to think of method calls as *message passing*. You send a message to the object "please give me the result of the `isBlind()` method". The object goes "OK, I know how to do `isBlind()`, does it, then sends a message to the caller containing the result.

Your `Owl` object receives that message asking to run `isBlind()`. It doesn't care where it came from. It doesn't know what the caller knows about it. It just runs its own version of `isBlind()` and sends the result back.

When you cast to a superclass (or an interface) in the caller, the caller "forgets" that it's talking to an `Owl`, but the `Owl` doesn't know that. It just keeps handling messages in the same way it always does.

This is the core of what makes polymorphism so powerful. It means you can put your `Owl` into a collection of `Nocturnal`, and call `isBlind()` on each one, getting the correct result:

```
  List<Nocturnal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
  animals.add(new Owl());
  animals.add(new Bat());

  for(Nocturnal animal : animals) {
      System.out.println(
           "Name: " + animal.getName() + 
           " Blind: " + animal.isBlind());
  }
```

As you progress with object-oriented programming, you will encounter tons of situations where this is invaluable. Not least, unit testing, in which you can substitute a *test double* (sometimes a *mock*) for the objects that collaborate with the object you're testing.

Note that modern Java programmers tend not to subclass all that often, preferring to to implement `interface`s much of the time. "Prefer composition to inheritance". The same principles apply regarding polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Though you cast `Owl` to `Nocturnal` still the `Owl` object contains the its methods. And that's why its printing `false` -

```
Nocturnal nocturnal = (Nocturnal) new Owl();
```

The casting here just make the newly created `Owl` object compatible for `Nocturnal` references - "`nocturnal`"

So when you call the method of `isBlind()` you are actually calling the `isBlind()` of `Owl` object which is just referenced by (or stored in) `nocturnal` of type Nocturnal. Here we say dynamic polymorphic is happen.

Answer (score 1):

When a sub class *overrides* a method of its base class then each invocation of the *overridden* method from outside the sub class (including the base class) will always result in invoking the overriden method.

The casting has no impact on the behavior of the method. If its overriden its overridden for the outside world.

Only way to invoke the method as per behavior provided by base class is by using `super` keyword with `.` ( dot operator ) from inside the instance method of the sub class.